# Backing up ancient hardware

Tags: backup

I've been asked to create a backup of an old, old laptop.

It's a 386 with 640KB + 1MB of RAM, a floppy disk drive and a serial port.
The HD is 80MB.
Ideally I'd still like to get an HD image out of it so I can try to get the software running in vmware/qemu/dosbox/...

Ordinarily I'd boot the system with a linux live CD and copy the HD image over the network. Obviously that won't work here.

I've considered a linux boot disk and transferring the image over a serial connection but I don't even know where to begin looking for something that will even boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB drive enclosures are pretty cheap -- you can get one for under $10. Drop the drive into the enclosure, plug it into your machine and use your favorite imaging tool (Clonezilla, for instance).

(As an alternative to USB you can also go with a 2.5 to 3.5 IDE adapter and just connect it to your PC.)

Comment: 386 laptop is very likely to have some crazy HDD. Neither compatible with PATA 40 pin cables, nor with modern 2.5" laptop standard.

Comment: I removed the hard drive and it at least has the same PIN layout as a modern laptop drive.
Hooking it up to the USB adapter doesn't seem to work but that might be because the drive is as good as dead.

Comment: What model is it? Look for numbers on it and google it.

Comment: I think you'd have to connect the IDE drive. A machine that old wouldn't have USB (unless you could find an ISA card to add USB ports).

Comment: @DannySmurf -- Just to clarify, the idea would've been to connect the old laptop's drive to a USB enclosure and connect that to another machine to do the actual imaging.

Answer (score 4):

you can use Norton Ghost for DOS to boot from floppy disk and backup the drive image accross your network or via a parallel port connection with a hi-speed bidirectional LPT cable, instructions here:

**[Radified's Guide to Norton Ghost: Imaging (Ghosting) Across a Network](http://ghost.radified.com/ghost_network.htm)**

if you don't happen to have a PARCP (Laplink) cable handy, here you find a [schematic diagram](http://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/generic/0,295582,sid7_gci1050017,00.html#). DIY from two old printer cables.